# How to install Vuetify with Laravel8 Vue3 app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, laravel-8

I am currently creating a Todo app in Laravel 8 + Vue3.

I have attempted to install Vuetify to get the design right, but it does not work.

According to my research, Vuetify is not supported in Vue3, is it not available in vue3?

The following is the error log.

```
PS C:\Users\shozo\Documents\programming\laravel-todolist\todolist\todolist_app> npm install vuetify
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.45
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.2.31" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.6.4" from vuetify@2.6.12
npm ERR! node_modules/vuetify
npm ERR!   vuetify@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\shozo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shozo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-20T12_39_49_817Z-debug-0.log
```

Here is my development environment

```
Laravel Framework 8.83.8

todolist_app@ C:\Users\shozo\Documents\programming\laravel-todolist\todolist\todolist_app
├─┬ @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@3.0.0-5
│ └── vue@3.2.31 deduped
└─┬ vue@3.2.31
  └─┬ @vue/server-renderer@3.2.31
    └── vue@3.2.31 deduped

PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2022 10:18:23) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

PS C:\Users\shozo\Documents\programming\laravel-todolist\todolist\todolist_app> npm -v
8.5.0
```

I want to use vuetify in my current project

If I can't, I will re-create it with vue version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify has very recently released [v3.0.0](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/) which does support VueJS 3.
In order to install the very latest version of Vuetify 3 from npm, use the package found under [@vuetify/nightly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuetify/nightly/v/3.0.2). At the time of writing this latest nightly version can be installed using the following command:

```
npm i @vuetify/nightly@3.0.2
```

You can check other versions of the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuetify/nightly/v/3.0.0?activeTab=versions).

Comment: Thanks for the info!
I was able to install it successfully!